# Dual-booted with Windows and I don't want Windows anymore

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I dual-booted with Windows a while ago. Now I want to delete Windows (already did it) and make elementary take the rest of the hd without having to reinstall the system.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I think he wants to add whatever the windows partition was using to his elementary OS partition without reinstalling his elementary OS

Comment: I think there's no problem doing that. haven't done it in a while, but I think there's no problem to resize a petition using gparted or any other partition tool

Answer (score 1):

I think it should not be a problem.

here's one link [how to live resize main partition](https://codesilence.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/live-resizing-of-an-ext4-filesytem-on-linux/)

I'm sure there are easier ways to do it with gparted or similar software (**haven't done it myself in a while**)

Or you can just mount it as a separate partition and use it for data storage.